# Android: Alternatives to AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, frameworks

for my app I made a framework for all network calls to an external API. I put everything in "Services" like: `UserService`, `MessageService` etc. So now when I want to call a network method I can't do this in the UI-Thread of my `Activity` so I made an `AsyncTask` and everything was just fine =)

But now I want something like giving the method to execute to the `AsyncTask` so I don't need to write an `AsyncTask` for every method of my network-framework. So instead of having something like this:

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<UserService, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(UserService... params) {
        UserService userService = params[0];
        userService.getUser();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want something more "abstract" so the `AsyncTask` doesn't need to know the "getUser" method? But I can't find any idea of how to do this... Maybe the AsyncTask is not good for this anyway?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking, but `IntentService` is commonly used as an alternative to `AsyncTask`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly either, but an alternative to AsyncTask are loader, actually you should prefer them. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I don't know how to express this properly so searching the web wasn't helpfull too. I'm trying to explain again: in the "doInBackground" method I don't want to call "userService.getUser" explicitly because there are many other methods and services that do network calls and because I can't execute them on the Main/UI Thread I need e.g. an AsyncTask. But I just want to have one AsyncTask for every network method...

Comment: You can create your own interface and pass that to your **Generic** `Asynctask`. i suggest that you check *Retrofit* form square or *Volley* from google for network operations they are faster in network operations according to this article http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: Hm I don't see how it would be possible to use my network framework for this (this framework only will know all the urls and parse JSON in nice Objects to return to my android application)

Comment: I'm considering using reflection but that's not nice isn't it^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are plenty AsyncTask alternatives :

> https://android-arsenal.com/tag/9

and plus Needle - Multithreading library for Android

> http://zsoltsafrany.github.io/needle/

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use a third party library like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
If you work with images I strongly suggest [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 5):

Remember that Android has a limit of threads and AsyncTasks.

You can use 2 libraries to do the same work of AsyncTasks:

1. Volley -> http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/
2. LoopJ -> http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Update:

I really recommend Retrofit 2.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 3):

**RxJAVA is best option**

Alternative to Asynctask for Web service call,file upload,file download is
[Android Fast Networking Lib](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking)

For other case 
you can use following [method](https://stablekernel.com/replace-asynctask-and-asynctaskloader-with-rx-observable-rxjava-android-patterns/)

```
 Disposable d = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<HashMap<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public HashMap<String, String> call() throws Exception {
            // will run in background thread (same as doinBackground)
                return postParam;
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(final HashMap<String, String> data) throws Exception {

        // will run in UI thread. write down code for on PostExecute
                    }

                });
    // write down code for on preExecute
        DisposableManager.add(d);
```

// dispose object

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        DisposableManager.dispose();
    }
        // Dispose manager class


 import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
    import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;

    public class DisposableManager {

        private static CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

        public static void add(Disposable disposable) {
            getCompositeDisposable().add(disposable);
        }

        public static void dispose() {
            getCompositeDisposable().dispose();
        }

        private static CompositeDisposable getCompositeDisposable() {
            if (compositeDisposable == null || compositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
                compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
            }
            return compositeDisposable;
        }

        private DisposableManager() {}
    }
```

Comment: here it is not fixed to use HashMap<String, String> you can use any datatype based on your requirment

Answer (score 2):

If you dont prefer third party libraries and prefer library with simplicity and good documentation and support, **Loaders** is the best choice.

For our delight, AsyncTaskLoader(subclass of Loaders) performs the same function as the AsyncTask, but better and also can handle Activity configuration changes more easily.And best thing is it behaves within the life cycles of Fragments and Activities.

For more information and subclasses please check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Comment: Just a side note. as of API 28 it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders should be used instead of directly using Async tasks. There are specific Loader API's for specific operations like perform transations in sqlite database etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have post for this there are multiple solutions for this to replace asynctask like using

1. Executors Service
2. RxJava
3. Listenable Futures
4. Courotines using Kotlin

here is my Implementations

[click the link below to see implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123689/how-do-i-replace-asynctask-with-rxjava-observer/65107392#65107392)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Kotlin** and **Coroutines** it is pretty simple to implement it by yourself:

```
fun <P, R> CoroutineScope.executeAsyncTask(
        onPreExecute: () -> Unit,
        doInBackground: suspend (suspend (P) -> Unit) -> R,
        onPostExecute: (R) -> Unit,
        onProgressUpdate: (P) -> Unit
) = launch {
    onPreExecute()

    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        doInBackground {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { onProgressUpdate(it) }
        }
    }
    onPostExecute(result)
}
```

`executeAsyncTask` is an extension function on `CoroutineScope`. Having any `CoroutineScope` instance with `Dispatchers.Main` context, for example [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) we can call this function like the following:

```
viewModelScope.executeAsyncTask(
    onPreExecute = {
        // ... runs in Main Thread
    }, doInBackground = { publishProgress: suspend (progress: Int) -> Unit ->
        
        // ... runs in Background Thread

        // simulate progress update
        publishProgress(50) // call `publishProgress` to update progress, `onProgressUpdate` will be called
        delay(1000)
        publishProgress(100)

        
        "Result" // send data to "onPostExecute"
    }, onPostExecute = {
        // runs in Main Thread
        // ... here "it" is a data returned from "doInBackground"
    }, onProgressUpdate = {
        // runs in Main Thread
        // ... here "it" contains progress
    }
)
```

The main condition is that the `CoroutineScope` should have `Dispatchers.Main` context. `viewModelScope` has it by default.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Volley library which does it work on the background thread and gives you control back to main thread when things are done.

Comment: i have used volley for thousands of records calling, but it getting app hanging / lags. So, i am not prefer volley for many more response data. else volley is excellent.