# Is it possible to use async task with in a sparate thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to execute the async task which is also a separate thread in a background working thread but it is giving me error, there is any another alternative to use async task/hit api in a separate thread?

log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
```

Comment: Provide code using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: How are you calling your AsyncTask?

Comment: 2015 ... still using AsyncTask ... I seriously hope you guys aren't doing this.

Comment: @Ascorbin Alternative and best way?

Comment: Alternative to AsyncTask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416158/android-alternatives-to-asynctask , It still depends what you are trying to accomplish tho !

Comment: @Developer For http stuff: libs like AsyncHttpClient, Volley, Retrofit. For everything else async: RxJava.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask instances can only be used one time.

just call your task like new MyAsyncTask().execute("");
and also asynctask instance must be created on the UI thread.