# I am creating change password functionality in my android application which crashing on getResponsecode()

Tags: android, performance, android-internet

I have provided onCreate() and New password method where on debugging, it is crashing on getResponsecode(). It is crashing and not getting response. It is not going to get response from server.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.change_password_activity);
        list(getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_Object"));
        CurrentPwdCheck();
        NewpwdCheck();

        btnSubmit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    NewPwd();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void NewPwd() throws IOException, JSONException {

        String myPwd=new_pwd.getText().toString();

        String Surl="http://inmeets.com/ChangePwd.php?uid="+uid+"&NewPwd="+myPwd;

        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;


            url = new URL(Surl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
       if( conn.getResponseCode()==203) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "your password changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: put some error log here.

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Did you using any DB to store your login credentials?

Comment: First print response code & then decide your condition.

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam no sir I am using filesystem concept and storing it on html file on server for backend I have used php should I put php code here ?

Comment: @KuldeepKulkarni i e I should do in this way ?    conn.getResponseCode();
        if(conn.getResponseCode()==200)
        {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "your password changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

Comment: @Gowtham Subramaniam                                                                   
   my php code                                                                                      <?php
$uid=$_GET["uid"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
$uid=str_replace("@","",$uid);
$uid=str_replace(".","",$uid);
$filename="data/".$uid.".html";
$data=file_get_contents($filename);
$json_parse=json_decode($data);
//print_r($json_parse); 
if($json_parse[0]->Email==$_GET["uid"] && $json_parse[0]->Password==$password)
echo $data;
?>

Comment: are you trying write data to the sd card in some where of your application?

Comment: @chalitha geekiyanage no I am writing it in json string on html file

Comment: What does `It is crashing` actually mean?

Comment: @aishwaryak I don't know about PHP. But in my case i won't import any php files for this concept. We get only JSON Response for common web service concepts

Comment: You also using JSON concept, then why you need those files?

Comment: @ Gowtham Subramaniam  yes sir but I am unable to get response from server side this php file is on server.I am not importing it. I am just getting response from it.

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam yes those files are needed only to save data on server

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform network actions from main thread because it will slow down the UI. Create a new AsyncTask to interact with your server.

Comment: ok there is only option of async Task only ? to separet it from main thread ?

Comment: There are many options but AsyncTask is most common. Is there any problem with AsyncTask ?

Comment: @ Ahamad Anees  no there is no problem for async task there is problem with getting response from server while debugging my apllication is crashing on getting response

Comment: AsyncTask will be better and easy.

Comment: Check wheather your Response equals to your JSON Response?

Comment: @Ahmad Anees  what are the other options ??to perform netwrok operation?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416158/android-alternatives-to-asynctask) are many. But still I dont't understand why are you not using it.

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam how to check response is equal to JsonResponse ?

Comment: @AhamadAnees ok yes i wil use async task only ! I am creating chatting application.in that I am using asyncTask for almost all activities does it write way to code ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "does it write way to code".

Comment: Get Response code from JSON and compare it with this concept. Because you can easily find where you getting error.   [Click Here](https://pastebin.com/DQviEPaM)

Comment: @AhamadAnees i e sir does it use async task for each activity ??

Comment: Yes.But in your case, it is not the cause of app crash. Can you include complete logcat ?

Comment: @AhamadAnees FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.aishwarya.registerlogin, PID: 23846
                                                                                     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)

Comment: @AhamadAnees sir I am unable to paste here full logcat as this textbox don't permit me to it on stackoverflow

Comment: It is ok. Network on main thread is the reason. Try with AsyncTask. It will work

Comment: @AhamadAnees AsyncTask Code Reference for aishwaryak

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't notice the link.

Comment: Its Okay... Refer this link [Source Code](https://pastebin.com/TqfH4Gpp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use thread instead of AsyncTask. But AsyncTask  would be preferably good because it is intelligent than thread in thread you have to manage all thing like run network call on background and update the UI in main thread.
If you really want some different than AsyncTask bellow is the thread concept

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.change_password_activity);
            list(getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_Object"));
            CurrentPwdCheck();
            NewpwdCheck();

            btnSubmit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    try {
                       NewPasword pwd = new NewPasword();
                       pwd.start(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    class NewPasword extends Thread{
            @Override
            public void run() {
            String myPwd=new_pwd.getText().toString();

            String Surl="http://inmeets.com/ChangePwd.php?uid="+uid+"&NewPwd="+myPwd;

            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;


                url = new URL(Surl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
           if( conn.getResponseCode()==203) {
     getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "your password 
                     changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

           }
            }
        }
```