# How do I replace Asynctask with RxJava Observer?

Tags: android-studio, asynchronous, rx-java, android-room

I have a test project with `Room` database. Using `Asynctask` I can successfully insert an object with some test data into the database. I'm trying to learn `RxJava` and replace `Asynctask` with `RxJava's` `observer`, but it doesn't work. I have read alot of documentation and watched tutorials, but I don't think I quite get it. Here's the relevant code:

Here I set my `Room` object with the data from my `List`:

```
for(ObjectForArray item: listToDatabase) {
        myRoomEntity.setName( item.getName() );
        Log.d( "TAG", myRoomEntity.getName() );
    }
```

Then I try to use `RxJava` `Observable` to insert data into the database. This was originally and successfully done using `Asynctask`:

```
Observable<MyRoomEntity> myRX = Observable
            .just(myRoomEntity)
            .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
            .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() );

myRX.subscribe( new Observer<MyRoomEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.d("TAG ONSUBSCRIBE", d.toString());

            try {
                myViewModel.insertDatabase( myRoomEntity );
                Log.d( "TAG", "Populating database Success" );
            }catch(Error error) {
                Log.d( "TAG", error.toString() );
            }
        }
```

The `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnComplete` are empty.

When I run the project it crashes with the error:

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

I'm obviously using `RxJava` wrong since the point is to do asynchronous tasks away from the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try restructuring your code like this:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> myViewModel.insertDatabase(myRoomEntity))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(() -> Log.d("TAG", "Populating database Success"),
                        throwable -> Log.d("TAG", throwable.toString()))
```

Considerations:

1. If your myRoomEntity is not available before this whole construct gets subscribed, make sure you use `defer` http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html
2. Your subscribe section handlers are operating on "main", that's why you were receiving a crash.
3. If possible, avoid unnecessary `just` calls

Comment: Awesome! It worked great! Thanks a bunch @ror for taking the time :)

Comment: One thing though. How do I trigger the onComplete method? Since I don't have an object I can't get ahold of the method. I tried adding .onComplete at the very end, but that didn't work...

Comment: Oh, wait, it did work to add .doOnComplete( () -> Log.d( "TAG", "COMPLETED" )) before .subscribe nice!

Comment: Actually,  the first action handler in subscribe block is "complete" one (for observable it would be "next"). But yes, your approach works as well.

Answer (score 3):

i have use RX java in replace of Asyntask as it has been deprecated in android 9
there are multiple replacements that android provides like Executors, threads, Listenable Futures , Coroutines , so you are looking how to implement this with rxjava and how RX Java java helps your to migrate just add these dependencies first in gradle

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
```

once you import lets start working with RX java i will let you know where you can put background task, pre execute, on post execute like asynctask

lets start codding with Rx java first , i have comment in the method that will help you to put the code

```
 Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {

            /// here is your background task


            return true;
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    //// pre execute here is my progress dialog

                    showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.scanning));

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {

                    //// here is on sucess you can do anystuff here like
                    if (aBoolean){

                        /// if its value true you can go ahead with this

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    /// this helps you to go if there is any error show dialog whatever you wants here

                    Log.e("error of kind",e.getMessage() );

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                    /// when your task done means post execute


                }
            });
```

once its done lets start working with implementation

```
  Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {

            /// here is your background task
            uribitmap =  getScannedBitmap(original, points);
            uri = Utils.getUri(getActivity(), uribitmap);
            scanner.onScanFinish(uri);

            return true;
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    //// pre execute here is my progress dialog
                    showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.scanning));

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {

                    //// here is on sucess you can do anystuff here like
                    if (aBoolean){

                        /// if its value true you can go ahead with this

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    /// this helps you to go if there is any error show dialog whatever you wants here

                    Log.e("error of kind",e.getMessage() );

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                    /// when your task done means post execute

                    uribitmap.recycle();
                    dismissDialog();
                }
            });
```

now i will do this with executors :

```
 /// pre execute you can trigger to progress dialog
            showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.scanning));

            ExecutorService executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executors.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //// do background heavy task here
                    final Bitmap uribitmap =  getScannedBitmap(original, points);
                    uri = Utils.getUri(getActivity(), uribitmap);
                    scanner.onScanFinish(uri);
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //// Ui thread work like
                            uribitmap.recycle();
                            dismissDialog();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are trying to insert an Object on the main (UI) thread.

You should do something like this:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> myViewModel.insertDatabase( myRoomEntity ))
            .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
            .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() );
```

And then use an Observer to subscribe to the Observable.

Comment: Oh, I see. So which is the main thread and the asynchronous thread? Must be confused about the names. Where should the `insert` code go?

Comment: I assume that this: myViewModel.insertDatabase( myRoomEntity ) is your insert code. Check the answer again.

Comment: Upvoted however as it looks insert returns nothing, you better be using Completable and not  Observable.

Comment: @Alex OK, got it, but the insert part gives a weird error "no instance of type variable T exists so that void conforms to T"

Comment: @MarkTornej that's because apparently your insertDatabase is returning void. You should be using Completable.fromAction instead.

Comment: @ror Yes, my insertData is returning void. But why/what should it be returning? Its only supposed to insert data, right?